# Approach for the recipe application

Tags: ios

I am planning to make an recipe application. In this application firstly a list of categories will be displayed in tableView, when user selects particular category list of recipes will be displayed in another tableview (I will be using navigationcontroller for this). When user selects particular recipe another view will show the detail recipe ( which contains an image and text). Each recipe has different text and image. So how should i begin the application? Should i create an sql file having the recipe and category ? How can i display or draw different text in the view? there are about 100 recipes. I am having the text for each recipe.

Comment: You should show video by applying all recipes in your kitchen and should show them in the app. Its the best idea !!!

Comment: what you have tried ? we are here to help in any programming issue not to tell you how to begin with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a sample recipes app [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) using core data, take a look at it to grab some useful ideas.

You have several options for your data:

If your data is stored locally and you don't need to update them dynamically, then you have the following options:

1 store data in core data.

Apple describe core data as an intermediate level skills so I am not sure if you wanna learn the whole thing if you don't know them well yet.

2 store in a database file.

Your best choose is sqlite database. There are tons of examples you can google to get.

3 use property list.

A property list would probably the simplest one to go. However, I don't know how much data a plist normally should handle, you might wanna do a bit research on it and see whether that would fit your need.

4 you can also try using a text file or a string file.

I haven't use text file before but i think it is possible. A string file is best if you wanna have more than one language supported for your app. In apple's term, internationalized app.

If you wanna get recipes from server so that you can update them at any time, you will need to use web service calls or using embedded uiwebview controls to show the contents of your web page. I can talk more if that's the case. And of course, you can also store the recipe after you get them from web services by using one of the options mentioned above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to go with core data, sice the dataset is not quite big. The scenario you have outlined is quite simple. UITableViewController delegate methods will server your purpose well.

[Apple's documentaion on tableviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)
is quite helpful. If you have any further queries, please post a comment and let me know.

Comment: How to draw different text in uilabel for each recipe?

Comment: use the tableview delegate method, didselectRowATIndexPath and based on that value, fetch data from core data and set the properties of next view controller class and display them there.